# Player movement

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote this simple code that draws and then lets you move a rectangle, but even after I change the coordinates of the rectangle by calling the move_player_x_ function, it doesn't move at all. I don't understand why. I came here looking for clarification and a detailed solution to my problem.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

class Game():
    width = 800
    height = 600
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fill_screen(self, color):
        self.color = color
        self.screen.fill(self.color)

    def update_method(self):
        pygame.display.update()

game = Game()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    lead_x = game.width/2
    lead_y = game.height/2
    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0
    velocity = 0.2
    block_size = 10
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    def move_player_x_left(self):
        self.lead_x_change += -self.velocity

    def move_player_x_right(self):
        self.lead_x_change += self.velocity

    def move_player_y_up(self):
        self.lead_y_change += -self.velocity

    def move_player_y_down(self):
        self.lead_y_change += self.velocity

    def draw_player(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(game.screen, black, [self.lead_x, self.lead_y, self.block_size, self.block_size])

    def key_up_x_stop(self):
        self.lead_x = 0

    def key_up_y_stop(self):
        self.lead_y = 0

    def constant_x_movement(self):
        self.lead_x += self.lead_x_change

    def constant_y_movement(self):
        self.lead_y += self.lead_y_change


player = Player()

exitGame = False
while not exitGame:
    game.fill_screen(white)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exitGame = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player.move_player_y_up()
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player.move_player_y_down()
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player.move_player_x_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player.move_player_x_right()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player.key_up_y_stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player.key_up_x_stop()
    player.constant_x_movement()
    player.constant_y_movement()        

    player.draw_player()
    game.update_method()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You never redraw the player after you change the x or y

Answer (score 3):

The code in the event loop is not indented correctly. Here's a corrected version:

```
while not exitGame:
    game.fill_screen(white)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exitGame = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.move_player_y_up()
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.move_player_y_down()
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.move_player_x_left()
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.move_player_x_right()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.key_up_y_stop()
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.key_up_x_stop()
```

Also, in the `...stop` methods, you have to set `lead_x_change` and `lead_y_change` to 0 not `lead_x` and `lead_y`.

```
def key_up_x_stop(self):
    self.lead_x_change = 0

def key_up_y_stop(self):
    self.lead_y_change = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code, i added a function in the player object `move_player` with local booleans `bUp,bDown,bLeft,bRight`. If python had enumerations, it would be so much better. Any how, on event KEY DOWN and KEY UP, they toggle these booleans in the player. after the input is calculated and these booleans are toggled/set, it called `move_player()` in player object that checks its booleans and sets a while loop while one is true and adds velocity in the respected location and redraws player.
Here the source i got for you...

```
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

class Game():
    width = 800
    height = 600
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fill_screen(self, color):
        self.color = color
        self.screen.fill(self.color)

    def update_method(self):
        pygame.display.update()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    lead_x = 800/2
    lead_y = 600/2
    velocity = 0.002
    block_size = 10

    bUp = false 
    bDown = false 
    bLeft = false 
    bRight = false

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    def draw_player(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(game.screen, black, [self.lead_x, self.lead_y, self.block_size, self.block_size])

    def move_player(self):
        while bLeft:
            self.lead_x += -self.velocity
            self.draw_player()
        while bRight:
            self.lead_x += self.velocity
            self.draw_player()
        while bUp:
            self.lead_y += -self.velocity
            self.draw_player()
        while bDown:
            self.lead_y += self.velocity
            self.draw_player()

game = Game()
player = Player()

exitGame = False
while not exitGame:
    game.fill_screen(white)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exitGame = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.bUp = true
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.bDown = true 
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.bRight = true
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.bLeft = true
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.bUp = false
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.bDown = false 
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.bRight = false
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.bLeft = false
    player.move_player()
    game.update_method()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: I did as you asked (edited the code for you to see) but it only lets me move the rectangle once!

Comment: @LolLol , you may have to incorporate a bool with it, too; I understand what you're saying. Psuedo: on key press(lets say, left), bmoveleft = true. while bmoveleft is true, lead_x plus or minus velocity, on key release bmoveleft = false, this stops the while loop and stopping the movement.

Comment: So something like this:(?)

if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            bmove_Up = True
            while bmove_Up is True:
                player.move_player_y_up()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        bmove_Up = False
It still doesn't work! :(

Comment: @LolLol, i edited my post with a new solution I think would work. I added a new function in your player class and 4 new booleans. Lemme know what you think and if that works. I have to do this same sort of 'logic' with javascript in the past.

Comment: @LolLol What is the result? Still moving in steps or not at all?

Comment: Not moving at all :(

Comment: You probably wanted to use `if` statements instead of `while` loops in the `move_player` method. The while loops there don't make sense. Also, `false` and `true` should be capitalized.